# Adjusting set_line_width() to correct ratio?

Tags: graphics, cairo

I'm using Cairo to draw figures. I found that Cairo uses a "absolute coordinate" when drawing. It is a flexible and comfortable way, except specify the `line_width`. Because of the ratio of the below image is not 1:1, when the "absolute coordinate" converted to "real coordinate", the width of the lines are not same.

```
WIDTH = 960
HEIGHT = 640

surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
ctx.scale(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

ctx.rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
ctx.set_source_rgb(255, 255, 255)
ctx.fill()

ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
ctx.move_to(0.5, 0)
ctx.line_to(0.5, 1)
ctx.move_to(0, 0.5)
ctx.line_to(1, 0.5)
ctx.set_line_width(0.01)

ctx.stroke()
```

What is the correct way to make `line_width` shown as the same ratio in the output image?

Answer (score 0):

Undo your call to `ctx.scale()` before calling `stroke()`, for example via:

```
ctx.save()
ctx.set_line_width(2)
ctx.identity_matrix()
ctx.restore()
```

(The `save()`/`restore()` pair applies all your transformations again afterwards)